# Openssl read and regular write

Tags: openssl

I have a generic question,

I am trying to use Openssl in my application for reads and writes over the TCP/IP network communication.

The server creates a socket and binds and listens to it. It loops to accept any incoming connections from any clients.

My question is - 
Can I do a `SSL_read()` to receive any incoming bytes over the network but use a `writev()` to write out any bytes to the network ?

There are some reasons for not doing writes using SSL (old policies which I am trying to get changed). But in the meantime, is that possible/OK to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do a `SSL_read()` to receive any incoming bytes over the network but use a `writev()` to write out any bytes to the network ?

No. TLS requires uninterrupted two-way communications between the peers. Injecting non-TLS data into the connection will cause an error.